# XML Expression binding possible only using the bound DataSet?

Tags: sapui5

In my app I have a master view with employee selection (bound to entity set EmployeesList) and an Entry view where I add some data to the selected employee (bound to AttAbsType).

I would like to make some fields visible or hidden in the Entry view based on the field "schkz" in the EmployeesList entity set. Is it possible to access values from a DataSet different than to what is bound to the current view?

The screen logic is:

1. Employee selection view (read basic data including the schkz value)
2. Details view to show existing entries
3. Entry view to add new entries. Here I would like to use schkz value of the selected employee to show/hide fields.

Image of the whole model:
[Odata model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlrBK.png)

In the console I can test that the value is there even while I'm in the Entry view:

```
sap.ui.getCore().getModel("schkz");
```

But in the Details view I can't use this value directly for expression binding. I tried like this:

View:

```
<Input id="__input0" visible="{= ${schkz} === 'NORM' }"/>
```

Even if I copy the value to a hidden label and try to use that label, it doesn't work:

Controller:

```
this.byId("_label21").setText(schkz);
```

View:

```
visible="{= ${_label21} === 'NORM' }"
```

I can see the value in the screen but the expression binding doesn't work using it. This is just to test that I really can access the value from core.

Is this even possible using only expression binding? If not, what is the simplest way to get this working? Add the field to the AttAbsTypeSet even though it doesn't logically belong there? Or do the whole thing in the controller and hide/show the fields there?

thanks for any tips! :)

Comment: Your bindings do not make any sense and cannot work. Please post the structure of your model data as well. In general it is NOT useful to bind master data in the detail view as you cannot ensure that the master data are loaded, e.g. if your detail view is load through direct navigation master data might not be loaded on small devices as the master is not loaded

Comment: I guess they are a bit hazy at best :) I just tried to show that I have the data from the backend, and now I would like to use it in the Details view but the view can't see it when it comes to expression binding.


In this app it is impossible to go to the Details screen without selecting the employee first, so we always have the value schkz at hand.


So, where should I stick it in order to use it in the view? Is the only option to add it to the Entity Set which is bound to the Details view?

Comment: As mentioned: Post an example of your data. What is schkz? Is it the model name or a property. It is not clear from your example?

Comment: Done, please see the original post.

Answer (score 0):

During the routing from the Master View to the Details View, you can pass parameters. They would be passed as a parameter object in the `navTo` function.

```
this.getRouter().navTo("DetailsScreen", {selectedMasterId: <PlaceIdHere>});
```

Then, on the Details Screen controller, you can read this parameter and set up the details screen accordingly.

I would do this by attaching a PatternMatched event to the Init method on the Details Controller like this:

```
onInit: function () {
    this.getRouter().getRoute("Details").attachPatternMatched(this.onPatternMatched, this);
}


onPatternMatched: function (oEvent) {
    var thePassedID = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").selectedMasterId;
    // Do logic with the ID next.
}
```

For this to work, you need to define the parameter in the manifest file also.

```
"routing": {
    ...
    "routes" : [
        ...
        {
            "pattern": "Details/{selectedMasterId}"
            "name": "Details"
            "target": "Details"
        }]
    ...
    }
```

This parameter is passed in the URL and can be read by the user in the address bar so depending on your purposes, this may not be ideal.

From here, you could set up your binding based on the id of the record you are trying to show and bindings in the Details View could be relative to the datamodel set up this way.

Comment: Thank you for the idea! Do you think the variable "thePassedID" could be used in expression binding in the view if passed on like this?

Comment: You can set the field in the view with the data passed this way with simple javascript from the controller.`this.getView().byId("idvalue").setText(thePassedID)`. I don't think this is what you want though. I think you want to set up a model for the view based on the primary id of the detail page. Then have relative bindings defined in the view. If you set a model for the view called `myModel` in the controller using `this.getView().setModel(themodelObject, "myModel")`, you can then reference the model's fields with `{myModel>myField}` in the view definition.

Comment: You got it right, I don't want to show that value anywhere. I just want to use it to evaluate if I should show or hide a couple of fields. I was too vague, sorry. So, I could create this "helper" model just to contain this one field and use it?